# Replacing Values in Dataframe Based on Condition

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements, where-clause, apply

I am using a Dataframe in python that has a column of percentages.  I would like to replace values that are greater than 50% with 'Likely' and less than with 'Not-Likely'.

Here are the options I found:

```
df.apply
df.iterrows
df.where
```

This works for the df.iterrows:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
if row['Chance']>0.50:
    df.loc[index, 'Chance']='Likely'
else:
    df.loc[index, 'Chance']='Not-Likely'
```

However, I have read that this is not an optimal way of 'updating' values.

How would you do this using the other methods and which one would you recommend?  Also, if you know any other methods, please share! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot.

```
import numpy as np

df['Chance'] = np.where(df['Chance'] > 0.50, 'Likely', 'Not-Likely')
```

This will however make anything = to .50 as `'Not-Likely'`

Just as a side note, `.itertuples()` is said to be about 10x faster than `.iterrows()`, and `zip` about 100x faster.

Comment: I'm getting the following error when I do this: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Comment: It means you have strings in that column. You can’t ask or to check if a string is greater than a number value. Make sure there are no strings in the column, and make sure the column is a numeric datatype.